# Interop for macOS native data types and .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, macos, .net-core, interop

I'm currently writing a cross-platform headless C# Application using .net 6, and I need to access a few native macOS methods from the ApplicationServices framework.

I've got it working using P/Invoke for very basic stuff:

```cs
[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/ApplicationServices")]
private extern static bool AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(IntPtr options);
static bool IsProcessTrustedWithOptions()
{
    return AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

However, I'd like to use functions which are a bit more sophisticated, and use macOS types such as CFArray, CFString, etc... What would be a good way of achieving this? I noticed that [dotnet's source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c2ec86b1c552ac8a1749f9f98e012f707e325660/src/libraries/Common/src/Interop/OSX/Interop.CoreFoundation.cs) has got a bunch of interop code for native OSX data types, but it seems to all be internal... I'd also like to avoid using Mono or Xamarin (which only works with .net framework as far as I can tell).

An example of a function I'd like to use is `AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeNames(IntPtr AXUIElement, UnsafeMutablePointer<CFArray?>)`. But I'm a bit lost about how to provide it with a CFArray...

Comment: The CORE libraries are intended to be interoperable with any OS.  There is a runtime library for both MAC, Mono, and Xamarin (see : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet?force_isolation=true).  Core replaced Net so that windows code would run on Unix Servers and Phones.  The low level kernel functions are now fully compatible with Linux, MAC, and Windows.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure I fully understand your answer, but yes I'm aware that .net core (now just called .NET 6) is fully cross-platform, however as mentioned in my question, I'm looking to include macOS-specific code, which uses libraries only available on macOS.

Comment: If you want code to work with more than one operating system than you need to use methods that work on all operating systems.  So it is best to stay with Core methods.

Comment: No offense, but that's really not helpful given my question. If I was able to only use core methods, of course I would, but I need to use macOS-specific libraries - .NET supports platform-specific code (either through runtime verification or conditional compilation) and it also fully supports interop (as show by the example in my question).

Comment: The API Web kit has method.  Looks like kit has c language interface.  See : https://javascript.developreference.com/article/11838471/macOS+accessibility+API+on+WebKit+applications+with+AXTextMarker?force_isolation=true